# MS Word 2016: Changing the time format?

Tags: microsoft-word

I can't seem to figure out how to change the date and time format in MS Word 2016 from the English/US "Month/Day/Year"-format into the European "Day.Month.Year"- format.

I'm working on a document written in English but intended for European recipients. MS Word correctly recognizes the language as English, and only allows selecting between the common date formats for English language, and the format I want is not available in this list. How do I configure Word to use a time format of a different language also in English text, or alternatively, add a custom time format to a language?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can achieve this by clicking `Insert` > `Date & Time` and selecting another format (which is linked to the language you select on the right).

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Region settings to a different country on Windows to have a try:

Open **Control Panel** > **Region**, under **Formats** tab, set the Format to European country for example German (Germany). The **Short date** can be set to **dd.MM.yyyy** by default.

[image]

Finally, insert **Date & Time** in Word, check if German (Germany) is available for choosing and select the date format.